# Message Driven Bean deploy error in WildFly

Tags: jakarta-ee, jms, wildfly, message-driven-bean, jms-topic

I'm quite new to JMS and WildFly 10.0.0.CR5

I've started with a very simple task: adding a topic to the `default` server shipped with WildFly and deploy a MDB (in an EJB jar, and the EJB jar is inside an EAR) that listens on that topic. The code of the MDB is:

```
@MessageDriven(
        activationConfig = { 
                @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destination", propertyValue = "java:/jms/topic/test"), 
                @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destinationType", propertyValue = "javax.jms.Topic"),
                @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "acknowledgeMode", propertyValue = "Auto-acknowledge"),
                @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "subscriptionDurability", propertyValue = "Durable"),
                @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "subscriptionName", propertyValue = "mdbTestSubscription")
        }, 
        mappedName = "java:/jms/topic/test")
public class MessageDrivenBeanTest implements MessageListener {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MessageDrivenBeanTest.class);

    /**
     * Default constructor. 
     */
    public MessageDrivenBeanTest() {
        log.info(String.format("Building <%s>", this.getClass()));
    }

    /**
     * @see MessageListener#onMessage(Message)
     */
    public void onMessage(Message message) {
        log.info("Message received");
    }

}
```

Also, I disabled the `ExampleDS` that comes shipped. I will have to use mine ones.

When I try to deploy the EAR package I get the following error:

```
WFLYCTL0184:    New missing/unsatisfied dependencies:
      service jboss.naming.context.java.jboss.datasources.ExampleDS (missing) dependents: [service jboss.naming.context.java.comp."mytest-ear-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT"."mytest-jms-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT".MessageDrivenBeanTest.DefaultDataSource]
```

I got two questions, actually.

The first is: how do I configure correctly this `DefaultDatasource` mentioned in the error?

And a more general question: why is the MDB looking for a datasource, when I never asked for that?

Comment: Can you provide the full class as a code example? What packages did you implement? AFAIK You can leave out the mappedName = "java:/jms/topic/test" in the annotation.